# Calculated Column - Looking for highest column value per column

Tags: workflow, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Not sure if this is possible and am hardly a novice with any coding, but here it goes.

I'm trying to get the highest item value on specific columns that will be fluctuating over time. I'm not concerned with any value that is lower than the highest value recorded over time.

EG. - Jobsite X created with 4 barricades... 4 more barricades delivered (column now reads 8). Pick up 6 barricades (column now reads 2).

Is there a set of formulas I can use in a calculated column to get my "MAX" barricade output (in this case 8) for Jobsite X?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated column works on the current item. On other words it works across rows.

For your requirement I would recommend using JavaScript or Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it in SharePoint, as SharePoint is not Excel

You **can** open your SharePoint List in Excel